# How to get the variable value from a function in a same m file in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I want to make a GUI in matlab. In the (*.fig) file, There will be 2 push buttons. the first is to read the image from the directory, save it into a variable and show it in the matlab GUI.

so in the main file (*.m) i will have 2 functions that represent the 2 buttons.

for example in the main file (*.m), the first function : x=imread('image.bmp');

And the second button (the second function, in the same main file as a first function) is to make a process with a image that have read by the first button. so, i have to get the variable x from the first button (function) to do the process.
If i have get the x variable, i can send it to another *.M files.

How to get the x variable from the first function.

Here is my code..

```
THE MAIN FILE

%First button (Function)
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.bmp';'*.jpg';'*.gif';'*.*'},        
'Pick an Image File');
citra1 = imread([pathname,filename]);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(citra1);
handles.citra1 = citra1;
guidata(hObject, handles);
set(handles.text1,'String',filename);
```

% and here is my second button (function)

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[gambr1, psan1, jmlobjk1, brs1, klm1]=BacaCitra1(citra1);
 axes(handles.axes3);
 imshow(gambr1);
 handles.gambr1 = gambr1;
 guidata(hObject, handles);
```

i wanna send the "citra1" as a image variable from the first function to be read in the second function, so i can do

```
 [gambr1, psan1, jmlobjk1, brs1, klm1]=BacaCitra1(citra1);
```

but there are error messeges like :
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'citra1'.
Error in ==> deteksi2citra>pushbutton1_Callback at 117
[gambr1, psan1, jmlobjk1, brs1, klm1]=BacaCitra1(citra1);

 Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
    feval(varargin{:});

  Error in ==> deteksi2citra at 42
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

 Error in ==>        @(hObject,eventdata)deteksi2citra('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,even data,guidata(hObject))
 ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Thank you for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already doing what you need to do, in fact, it looks like you are using two methods in parallel. You save the variable `citra1` to the `handles` structure in `pushbutton1_Callback` and you are accepting that structure as a user variable in both callbacks. You are *also* saving `handles` with `guidata`.

See [Sharing Data Among a GUI's Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/sharing-data-among-a-guis-callbacks.html) and [guidata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) to see how you to extract `citra1` from `handles` in either case.

If you are setting the callbacks correctly, including the `handles` structure, then the short answer is to use `handles.citra1` instead of just `citra1` in your second callback. I highly recommend reading the callback documentation to understand what is happening, however.

Comment: wow thats great, thank you for the help Nigel. U make solve my problem :D

Comment: can u help me again in my another problem, Nigel ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651532/how-to-view-a-more-than-1-lines-of-sentences-to-uipanel-in-matlab