# How to view a more than 1 lines of sentences to uipanel in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, panel

I wanna view the result of the "Detection" function. 
In the "Detection" function there is "messeges" variable. 
From the function, i want that all the sentences in messeges variable can be preview in my GUI esspecially in UIPANEL.

How to do it. I have made a Panel design in matlab with tag=uipanel1.

```
[messeges]=Detection(handles.citra1); %it's to call the Detection     
function.
```

here is my UIPANEL CODE..

```
       hp1=uipanel('Position', [100 100 700 500],...
       'Title','UI Panel 1');
        set(hp1, [messeges]);
```

but it cannot display the sentences from the messeges variable into the panel1 that i had made before..

There are errors messeges like this

```
        ??? Error using ==> set
        There is no 'jumlah pasang pixel yang pada objek 13         
        adalah 1000' property in the 'uipanel' class.

       Error in ==> deteksi2citra>pushbutton3_Callback at 124
       set(hp1, [messeges]);

       Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

        Error in ==> deteksi2citra at 42
          gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

      Error in ==>          
     @(hObject,eventdata)deteksi2citra('pushbutton3_Callback',
    hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


     ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I have find the rellated topic but i cannot find the solution.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

There are three major problems with your code.

1. You always have to set **a property** of *an object* to *something* in *Matlab*.

   ```
   set(Object_Handle,'PropertyName1',PropertyValue1,...
      'PropertyName2',PropertyValue2...)
   ```

   Thus you might be able to write this `set(hp1, 'String', messages);` but never `set(hp1, [messages]);`
2. [`uipanel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) is just a container object, which means that it could contain other GUI objects. You could put a `text` or `edit` (See [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html)) containing your string in the [`uipanel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html). But the [`uipanel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) itself does not have a `'String'` property.
3. The *`position` vector* of [`uipanel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) is `normalized` by default. So all the position values must be between `0` and `1`. See position vector [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html#brdjixl-1) for more info.

### Example of putting **multi-line** `text` in `uipanel`:

(Note that this code is a standalone or self consistent code (unlike **GUIDE**), thus you can just copy and paste this code and run it in matlab command window.)

```
str = sprintf('Your \n Multiline \n String ...');

hp1 = uipanel('Title','UI Panel 1',...
    'Position', [.25 .1 .67 .67]);

uicontrol(...
    'Parent', hp1,...
    'Style','text',...
    'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1],...
    'String', str);
```

Comment: Thanx, it's work.. But if my messege is more than one line and i call it from the variable that processed in other function, how i can do it??
with the code above, the displayed messege is only the last line messege.

Comment: The message has to be a formatted string such as the output of `sprintf`. I assume that `Detection` is a user defined function. If so, the function has to be modified to generate a standard output string. Can you provide an example of `messages` and include it in your question?